# React CSS Modules and testing the component

Tags: reactjs, testing, css-modules

Inside my code I use babel-plugin-react-css-modules which is practically the same as react-css-modules

I have a code like this inside react component. 
`styleName` is for CSS Modules and I define styles for them inside countdownForm.local.scss
`className` represent my Bootstrap classes

```
import './countdownForm.local.scss'

class CountdownForm extends Component {
...
render () {
    return (
      <div styleName="first" className="container">
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

To test this component inside my test I have to use `ignore-styles` package because JavaScript can't handle CSS syntax and when we run unit tests, the test will try to import the CSS file without Webpack which will result error.

```
import register from 'ignore-styles'
import React from 'react'
import test from 'tape'
import CountdownForm from 'CountdownForm'

register(undefined, () => ({styleName: 'fake_class_name'}))

test('CountdownForm => should exist', (t) => {
  t.ok(CountdownForm)
  t.end()
})
```

By doing this everything passes great and test works without problem but I always get this warning in the console

> Warning: Unknown prop `styleName` on  tag. Remove this prop from
>   the element.

It is not a problem of functionality because tests works but it is annoying to get this message every time I run tests. How to fix, get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because you are not running the `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` compilation step before the test.

That works by replacing `styleName` prop with the computed CSS modules class names. Therefore `styleName` is never actually passed to the div in your real build (https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#how-does-it-work). It would rewrite your component to something like...

```
class CountdownForm extends Component {
  ...
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="container CountdownForm_first_123xyz">
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In your test, without running the babel plugin first, you will successfully manage to ignore the CSS import via `ignore-styles` but the props replacement hasn't happened so you end up passing a `styleName` prop to the `div`, which is not a defined property for `div` component, so React will warn you

Best way to fix this would be to run a babel compilation step before the test, that way you can also test the real localised classnames assignment

Comment: Hi alechill. That makes perfect sense but how do i run `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` before tests.It is defined within webpack and tests are outside the webpack bundle . I run the tests with the script  `"test": "babel-tape-runner \"test/setup.js\" \"test/**/*test.jsx\" | node_modules/.bin/tap-summary"` Inside the setup I just require jsdom and ignore-styles. I like it when I have styleName and className inside my code to easily destinguish and customize the two.

Comment: Well that runner should pipe through babel (using `.babelrc` for config) first so I'd make sure you have all the necessary plugins defined in that file

`{ "plugins": ["babel-plugin-react-css-modules"] }`

Comment: alechill i tried it but no luck. I put in answer above how my .babelrc and webpack look like.